# How do I create sub-folders in Onedrive

Tags: onedrive

I read an article about organizing files in OneDrive. The author discussed putting files in folders and sub-folders, but didn't give instructions for the sub-folders. I already know how to create folders, but I don't know how to create sub-folders. For example, I'm a first grade teacher and I want a folder called Math with sub-folders for addition and subtraction.

TIA

Marie

Answer (score 0):

After you've made the initial folder, go into it and you will see a bar which looks something like this:

[image]

Click on the down-arrow next to "New" and click on Folder.

[image]

Enter the folder name and that's it. You've made a sub-folder.